# Using express for cloud functions w/o losing the benefits of function profiling

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Diving into Cloud Functions, and I decided to use an Express app to manage my endpoints which looks like this....

```
const main = express();
// ...
exports.main = functions.https.onRequest(main);
```

And configured my `firebase.json` rewrites like so...

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/api/**",
    "function": "main"
  },
  ...
],
```

This is working great and does not require future `rewrite` updates. However one big downside that I noticed is that I no longer can profile my functions on an individual basis.

[image]

There are 5 endpoints being served inside of the `main` function.

Is there a recommended way to have a balance between convenience (using Express) and performance monitoring (individually listed functions on the dashboard)? I would love to use firebase monitoring but I don't like complicating my `firebase.json` rewrites.

Would it be crazy to make a separate express app for each function?

Comment: Go through this article. You might get some insights on how to organzine your cloud functions better [Organise your cloud functions](https://codeburst.io/organizing-your-firebase-cloud-functions-67dc17b3b0da)

Comment: Great link @mark922! I will definitely apply some of those ideas. Unfortunately they don't talk a ton about http triggers though.